# FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Write stream exhausted maximum allowed queued writes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I recently had a user run into an issue where none of their writes to Firestore were working.

From the logs, it seems like the writes to the local cache / IndexedDB layer was working fine and the real-time listeners were triggering from the local cache. However, none of the writes were saved on the server.

> FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Write stream exhausted maximum allowed queued writes.
> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.22.0): Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend.

Another thing is I changed GCP billing account for this project from one that was fully active to one that was on the free trial. I'm not sure if that would cause this issue due to some quota reason.

Obviously this error is not easy to replicate, so I want to see how to make sure it doesn't reoccur.

Answer (score 2):

This error is not related to billing.  You are almost certainly exceeding one of the limits as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). Note that the max sustained write rate to a single document is 1 per second:

> Maximum sustained write rate to a document
>
> 1 per second
>
> Sustaining a write rate above once per second increases latency and
> causes contention errors. This is not a hard limit, and you can
> surpass the limit in short bursts.

Comment: How can you catch this error? I'm doing this write as part of a batch and the batch seems to return successfully.

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately to explain what isn't working the way you expect with the code you have now.