# Firebase: Exceeding write quota when performing multiple api calls asynchronously [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am calling an api every 30 seconds with three different requests to get MLB, NFL, College Football games using ajax requests, so they all fire async. When they get responses, they begin writing the events to Firestore and some overlap comes up - I get errors saying I have exceeded the maximum write queue. I tried switching to batched writes so that all of the events from a single api call get written at the same time, but it still happens.

So my question is: **How can I prevent writing a Firebase Cloud Firestore batch when one is currently being written?**

Here are the error(s):

[2022-09-02T17:54:28.509Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.9.2): FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Write stream exhausted maximum allowed queued writes.

[2022-09-02T17:54:28.510Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.9.2): Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend.

Here is an example of one of the 3 api calls that I am using to batch write events:

```
$.ajax(apiMLB).done(async (response) => {
    try {
        //update firebase
        let batch = writeBatch(db); //create firestore batch
        for (let i = 0; i < response.events.length; i++) { //loop through events from api
            let ev = response.events[i]; //get a single event from the iteration
            let docRef = doc(db, "events", "" + ev.id); //check if event exists in fbase
            getDoc(docRef).then(docSnap => { //look up the event in firebase
                if (docSnap.exists()) { //if event is found, update it
                    batch.update(docRef, ev);
                } else { //if event is not found, add it
                    batch.set(docRef, ev);
                }
                if (i === response.events.length - 1) { //write batch after final element
                    console.log("wrote batch:");
                    console.log(batch);
                    batch.commit();
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
});
```

Comment: Did you search for the error message already, as it seems to have come up a few times before: https://www.google.com/search?q=FirebaseError%3A+%5Bcode%3Dresource-exhausted%5D%3A+Write+stream+exhausted+maximum+allowed+queued+writes.&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS983US984&oq=FirebaseError%3A+%5Bcode%3Dresource-exhausted%5D%3A+Write+stream+exhausted+maximum+allowed+queued+writes. Most likely it is what Doug answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64394490 about exceeding the quota on writing to the same document.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64394490) solve your issue?